# Save and instantly redirect from NewForm to EditForm, in Online 365. Old solutions does not work for me

Tags: edit-form, redirect, newform, save

Do You have working methods to redirect in SharePoint Online now? I'm trying to save item and then open Edit Form after clicking 'Save'. There were methods to do it before:
[link 1](https://spjsblog.com/2009/11/21/redirect-on-newform-and-editform-another-method/)
[link 2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/214363/need-to-have-a-save-and-stay-button-on-edit-form-no-redirect-after-submit)

but it redirects to default list view after save. Strange(!) that this code works, if there is error on page (if You don't fill required 'title' and try save - it shows warning and then reditects to page needed)

```
   // todo: add item id, '3' is for example
   var targetURL = '/products/Lists/Products/EditForm.aspx?ID=' + '3';

   // For Save Button
   var saveButton = jQuery("input[value='Save']");
   console.log(saveButton);
   saveButton.removeAttr("onclick");
   jQuery(saveButton).click = null;
   saveButton.click(function() {

       console.log("clicked");

       if (!PreSaveItem()) {
           console.log("!PreSaveItem");
           // return false;
       }

       if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) {
           //return false;
       }

       var oldUrl = jQuery('#aspnetForm').attr('action');

       var source = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldUrl);

       var newUrl = "";

       if (source) {
           console.log("Source key exist");
           newUrl = oldUrl.replace(source, encodeURIComponent(targetURL));
       } else {
           console.log("Source key not exists");
           newUrl = oldUrl + "?Source=" + encodeURIComponent(targetURL);
       }

       var elementName = jQuery(this).attr("name");
       WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newUrl, false, true));

       return true;

   });
```

## Update:

Ok, I think I've found problem: If I use this string - validation works, but "Save" always redirects to list root:

```
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) { 
return false; 
}
```

But if I comment this - form redirects as needed, but validation ("You cannot leave this blank") is ignored.  this problem is related with validation: 
[How do I trigger the default form validation without submitting the form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92864/how-do-i-trigger-the-default-form-validation-without-submitting-the-form)

So we need to add custom validation because `SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')` 
always returns true.

Imho for me it is easier to create custom page for adding item..

Thank You Nils for idea with guids! In my case I don't use [guid] culumn, but get latest id from list:

```
$.ajax({
url: webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Products')/items?$top=1&$orderby=Title desc",
method: "GET",
headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
},
success: function(data) {
    if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
        // here is last ID, so we can redirect to number+1
        var number = parseInt(data.d.results[0].Title, 10);
    }
},
error: function(data) {
    console.log("Error: " + data);
}
```

});

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in Online and also 2016 on prem and can verify the behaviour there.

However, it seems that giving the `Source` absolute still works, as long as it is a target in the current SiteCollection.

Comment: Greetings Nils! The question is about that I cannot do this step: "on 'save' modify the return-query-parameter to some special page and supply the guid". It always goes to list default view instead of provided 'Source'

Comment: Oh. Sorry. My mistake for not reading everything :-/ Does that happen on classic or modern or both?

Comment: Classic NewForm

Comment: if this behavoiur (redirect to list view) could not be overrided - the only way I see now is create custom html form instead of NewForm and redirect from this custom page :(..

Comment: Sadly, I can reproduce the same in 2016 on prem...

Comment: Thank You for confirmation, Nils! Looks like they changed something.. If You update Your answer I can mark it as answer (if You want)

Comment: I edited the answer. Try giving the `Source` absolute. That worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95665/discussion-between-gennady-g-and-nils).